# How can I monitor the Perl call stack?

Tags: perl, callstack

I'm using ActivePerl 5.8 on Windows XP.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
```

There are three subroutines used in my script.

To detect the call stack, I can only insert some `print "some location";` and check the print result from console Window.

Is there any good method to monitor it? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to monitor the call stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You weren't specific about why you'd like to monitor the call stack and trace your subs, so answers will have to be broad.

One method is [`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html):

> ### caller
>
> Returns the context of the current subroutine call. In scalar context, returns the caller's package name if there is a caller, that is, if we're in a subroutine or eval or require, and the undefined value otherwise. In list context, returns
>
> ```
> # 0         1          2
> ($package, $filename, $line) = caller;
> ```
>
> With EXPR, it returns some extra information that the debugger uses to print a stack trace. The value of EXPR indicates how many call frames to go back before the current one.
>
> ```
> #  0         1          2      3            4
>   ($package, $filename, $line, $subroutine, $hasargs,
> #  5          6          7            8       9         10
> $wantarray, $evaltext, $is_require, $hints, $bitmask, $hinthash)
>  = caller($i);
> ```

You might also use the [Devel::Cover](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Cover/) module:

> Code coverage data are collected using a pluggable runops function which counts how many times each op is executed. These data are then mapped back to reality using the B compiler modules. There is also a statement profiling facility which needs a better backend to be really useful.

The more you tell us about what you want to do, the more helpful to you our answers will be!

Answer (score 10):

If it's your code, you might want to use:

```
Carp::cluck( "And here's the stack:" );
```

See [`Carp::cluck`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Carp#NAME). It prints out a warning with a stack trace. It works like the "printf" style of debug output.

Answer (score 9):

Use the debugger's `T` command.

Example:

```
$ perl -d -e'
sub foo {}
sub bar { foo; }
bar;
'

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.32
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:4):   bar;
  DB<1> s
main::bar(-e:3):        sub bar { foo; }
  DB<1> s
main::foo(-e:2):        sub foo {}
  DB<1> T
. = main::foo() called from -e line 3
. = main::bar() called from -e line 4
  DB<1> s
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
  use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
  h q, h R or h o to get additional info.
  DB<1> q
```

Answer (score 0):

You rarely need to directly manage the call stack in Perl.  If you do `caller` is the tool you want.  However, it is only rarely needed.

More often, I want to see a stack trace when I am debugging.  Good news, its easy to get a stack trace, simply use [Carp](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html)'s `confess` and `cluck` functions instead of `die` and `warn`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;

bar(6.1);
bar(1);

sub foo {
    confess "Oh noes" unless @_ == 6;  # confess is fatal
}

sub bar {
    my $count = shift;
    cluck "bar is in trouble" unless int $count == $count;  # cluck is not fatal
    foo( ('a')x $count );
}
```

This gets you:

```
dao:~ toad$ perl test.pl
bar is in trouble at test.pl line 14
    main::bar(6.1) called at test.pl line 5
Oh noes at test.pl line 9
    main::foo('a') called at test.pl line 15
    main::bar(1) called at test.pl line 6
```